# How to refresh the Parent component after a button on child component is pressed?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, lifecycle

**Problem:**
I need to have the `parent component` to make another Apex call, `apiCallout()`, after the `save button` is clicked on the `child component`. That way the UI is displaying current `data`, however the current setup requires me to refresh the page after the `save button` is clicked to show the updated `data`. Would I need to send a variable in my `custom event` on `handleClickedSave()` to have the `parent component` make another `apex callout`?

**Parent HTML:**

```
<c-view var1={var1}></c-view>
<c-edit var1={var1}></c-edit>
```

**Parent JS:**

```
var1
async apiCallout(){
var2 = var1;
let payload = JSON.stringify({"test":var2});
this.var1 = await calloutToApi({params:payload});
}
connectedCallBack(){
apiCallout()
}
```

**Child View HTML:**

```
<template>
        <lightning-card  title="Hello">
            <lightning-button label="Edit" slot="actions" onclick={handleClickedEdit}></lightning-button>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body {var1}</p>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Child View JS:**

```
@api var1;
handleClickedEdit(){
//sends custom event to Parent to show Edit screen
}
```

**Child Edit HTML:**

```
<template>
        <lightning-card  title="Hello">
            <lightning-button label="Cancel" slot="actions" onclick={handleClickedCancel}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Save" slot="actions" onclick={handleClickedSave}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" value={var1}></lightning-input>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Child Edit JS:**

```
@api var1

handleClickedSave(){
//custom event to send to parent to show View Screen with Apex callout
sendUpdatePayloadToApi({params:var1})
}
handleClickedCancel(){
//custom event to send to parent to show View Screen without Apex callout
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child should notify the parent via an event:

```
// child.js
async handleClickedSave(){
  //custom event to send to parent to show View Screen with Apex callout
  await sendUpdatePayloadToApi({params:var1})
  this.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('recordsaved')
  )
}
```

---

```
<!-- parent.html -->
<c-edit onrecordsaved={refreshData}></c-edit>
```

---

```
// parent.js
async refreshData() {
  await this.apiCallout();
}
```

Comment: ah so this does work, thank you. Attaching this to my cancel button seems to work but for some reason the save button does not like it. Would I have to set up some delay?

Comment: to add to my comment above, when I put in an alert it will cause the refreshData function to work. But once removed, it does not function properly